# Is Ultimate Edition 6.3 real?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint

Ultimate Edition's a kinda Linux based on Ubuntu, the version listing on Ultimate Edition home page http://ultimateedition.info/ is 5.8, but the newest download from https://sourceforge.net/projects/ultimateedition/files/ is 6.3, is which the beta/alpha version?

Comment: What is exactly the purpose of this question?

Comment: Like the original comment here, but deleted

Answer (score 1):

[This “announcement”](http://ultimateedition.info/ultimate-edition-6-0-is-hot/) mentions version 6.3, so it would appear to be genuine.